# Targeted Learning in Data Science: background material

Tags: references, causality, epidemiology, high-dimensional, targeted-maximum-likelihood

I am interested in the use of modern causal inference methods to research the association between a (non-genetic) exposure, and endogenous molecules and/or health outcomes (high-dimensional data). I came upon the work of Prof. Mark J. van der Laan and his group in the USA, and it seems that it's probably what I need (but correct me if I am wrong). I decided to go through his book, *Targeted Learning in Data Science*, but I am facing multiple difficulties. Namely, I am not really used to the notation and some of the concepts are quite unclear to me. Can you suggest me any reference I can use as background material before tackling it? My background is on bioinformatics and I am currently doing PhD-level research in Epidemiology: I took courses in basic statistics and machine learning and I am reading the *What If* book.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568281/is-there-any-theory-or-field-of-study-that-concerns-itself-with-modeling-causati/568294#568294. Then the authors' own *Targeted Learning* book appears to precede (possibly even be a prerequisite for) *Targeted Learning in Data Science*.

Comment: These notes by Edward Kennedy go over much of the relevant background material. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.06469
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04740.pdf