# What should I study after finishing 'Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer'?

Tags: references, causality, dag

I have almost finished studying 'Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer', but I still feel that I need to learn more.
I considered 'Causality' (Pearl, 2009), but there seem to be several good learning resources about DAG (ex. Review Paper & etc).
What should I study after finishing 'Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer'?

Comment: Cunningham's [The Mixtape](https://mixtape.scunning.com/index.html) book or Huntington-Klein's [The Effect](https://theeffectbook.net/index.html) book would be suitable suggestions for a new starter. (Both books are free online too.) For something more formal would be the [What If](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/) book from Hernan & Robins and [Elements of causal inference](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/elements-causal-inference) by Peters et al.  These four *freely available* books would most likely cover the vast majority of CI use cases one come across.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you for answering my question. I interest 'Directed Acyclic Graph' for data analysis in Web Platform Business(ex. SNS, Commerce etc). I've been interested in the book 'Elements of causal inference' ever since. Can you give me a rough idea of what the 'Elements of causal inference' book contains?

Comment: It is the most advanced of the four books mentioned so I am not sure it is very constructive without enough background. (I am also not a huge fan of having very few exercises.) Dr. Peters has some excellent YouTube content, for example, the series [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvrcyqcN9Wo) - probably go through those first and refer to the book later. I know it is "uncool", but if you are interested in business applications do look at Econometrics literature. Pearl's work is not in a vacuum. That group has a *lot* of causal inference mileage.

Comment: (If you want to do "proper" DAGs, do check [Probabilistic Graphical Models](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models) by Koeller and Friedman. It is exceptional for the mathematical/theoretical background.)

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks so much for answering my question!

I'm not sure, but Elements of Causal Inference draws me in because it looks identical to Pearl's DAG perspective.

I have another question. 

1) What is 'proper' means? (I am not a native English speaker, so I do not understand the pronunciation of words well.)
2) How many preliminary knowledge of mathematics and statistics do i need for studying 'PGM'?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568281/is-there-any-theory-or-field-of-study-that-concerns-itself-with-modeling-causati/568294#568294

Comment: Sure, hit it. As mentioned probably do the lecture first, I found them very informative. 1. Regarding "proper": apologies, I meant it instead of "really good", it has informal use like: "Kevin is a proper player". I meant it provides a clear and rigorous foundation for the use of Bayesian Networks. 2. Pff... For PGM probably a class in Probability/Mathematical Statistics already. It is not meant to be an intro and neither is the Elements of Causal Inference.

Comment: Also consider Brady Neal's 'Introduction to Causal Inference' lectures on Youtube, with an accompanying free ebook (although the final chapters are still incomplete).